# returning generic Dictionary depending on type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic function that returns a Dictionary. If the key of the Dictionary is a string, I want to use the String.OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer.

This is my code:

```
    public static Dictionary<K,V> getDict<K,V>()
    {
        Dictionary<K,V> aDict;

        if(typeof(K)==typeof(string)) 
        {
            var stringDict = new Dictionary<string, V>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            aDict = (Dictionary<K,V>)stringDict;    // error here - can't convert.
        }
        else aDict = new Dictionary<K, V>();
// do more stuff here
        return aDict;
    }
```

However it tells me it

> can't convert a `Dictionary<string,V>` to a `Dictionary<K,V>`.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Dont make your generic method depend on type parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work the best for you:

```
var stringDict = new Dictionary<K, V>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as IEqualityComparer<K>);
```

The problem is that the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` ctor expects an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. `StringComparer` gives you an `IEqualityComparer` - the non-generic variety. Once you cast your equality comparer correctly, you should be on your way.

Test code block below will trigger the expected exception:

```
var dict = getDict<string, int>();

dict.Add("alpha", 1);
dict.Add("Alpha", 2);  // triggers the expected duplicate key exception.
```

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

Cast like this:

```
aDict = stringDict as Dictionary<K, V>;
```

Comment: And why wont that simply return null when the cast fails?

Comment: Well, in the case that we have here, we checked with an if statement that K is string. This is why we can be sure that the cast will not fail.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I assumed that if the cast was invalid the as would fail to because its effectively try-catching the cast

Answer (score 1):

One common solution - cast through intermediate cast to `object`:

```
  aDict = (Dictionary<K,V>)(object)stringDict;
```