# C# how to workaround contravariance in Func<T, bool>?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, casting, contravariance

Suppose I have following code:

```
class Program
{
    static IList<Func<object, bool>> _exclusions = new List<Func<object, bool>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        SetExclusions<PropertyInfo>(x => typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));           
    }

    public static void SetExclusions<T>(Func<T, bool> lambda)
        where T : class
    {
        Func<object, bool> l = (Func<object, bool>)lambda; // <= InvalidCastException
        _exclusions.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Of course it doesn't work because **T** type parameter in Func is contravariant - I can't pass **PropertyInfo** as more derived than **object**.

Is there a way to get around it? From my point of view it would be perfectly correct to do something like this afterwards:

```
foreach (var e in GetExclusions<PropertyInfo>())
{
    var a = members.Where(e);    
}
```

Comment: Make the class generic and add replace object with T? Of course then your list only has one input type, so youd need multiple different parameterized instances or static instances to accomplish your goal. What is the goal, by the way? Maybe a restructuring will fix it.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32555920/4400820) indicates that using `as` might work.

Comment: I resolved a similar problem with reflection and componing lambda, but it's no easy.

Comment: This is an extract from already quite generic and complicated class, I'd like avoid adding more complexity on the class level which affects interfaces it implements (or introducing new specialized class with type param for it) if there is easier semantic way.
The goal is to have collection of lambdas that can be used as predicates for Where() expression (last piece of code).

Comment: @BenKnoble Using `as` will just give you a null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before suggesting anything, the current design is most probably not appropriated to the problem you need to solve. So I'd really recommend revisiting it whenever there is a chance

Now to your question, one option could be casting the object to the expected type inside the lambda; 
Something like this:

```
Func<object, bool> l = o => lambda((T) o);
```

Then you could keep track in either a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, bool>>` of what type of expressions work for each different `Type`. There could be other alternatives if you don't want to keep a dictionary, but they would involve using a class that holds the same information

Comment: What makes you think it most probabaly not appropriated? The whole idea is quite simple: I have a class that performs XML serialization of given objects. I want it to be configurable about members to be seriazlied, so I want to iterate through serializing object members and create XmlIgnore attribute overrides. Probably it isn't the easiest approach but I just wonder can I have a collection of lambdas to be evaluated in the query of members list via reflection.

Comment: Because if you need to nest functions you are most likely missing something in your design that could prevent it. 

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve completely, you do create XmlIgnore overrides on the fly and then use the standard serializer?

If you know the types you are going to be querying before hand, then you can have different dictionaries for each one (if they are not many). If not you could model a Query pattern that has an Execute method and you declaratively specify what needs to be done. It really depends on how much you want to solve through design or statements

Comment: I use XmlSerializer because it's the easiest and yet flexible enough way to serialize objects. DataContract and other serializers don't fit by number of conditions. 
I need to set XmlIgnore attributes on the fly because i serialize Entity Framework objects and I need to control the graph being serialized (via set of conditions on members of serializing entity). Of course there is more straightforward declarative design with lots of code and statically typed membes but I prefer short semantic expressions (sometimes it's the only way to learn).

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. It changes the type of the lambda and in order to use it you need to cast parameter inside the lambda back before use in my case. Although this answer perfectly correct for the question formulated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's appeared to be more convenient  to store lambdas just in `List<object>` in this case you don't need to cast argument of the `Func<T, bool>` back and forth, just to cast lambda itself>:

```
List<object> _exclusions = new List<object>();
public IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> GetExclusions<T>()
{
   return _exclusions.OfType<Func<T, bool>>();
}
```